# Spring boot immediate return result fails to execute function

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to return immediate the result of a database query but I want to start a different thread that does some things.

Now I tried with an Executor like this:

```
  Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(
        () -> fooFunction(),
        1, TimeUnit.SECONDS
    );
```

but the function is not executed after the method returns.

Complete code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public FooDto updateInfo(UpdateTaskDto updateTask) {
       // updating the entity

    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(
        () -> fooFunction(),
        1, TimeUnit.SECONDS
    );

   return FooDto()
}
```

Where fooFunction is just a function that saves something to the database and returns void.

This updateInfo function is inside a @Service annotated class.

Why is this not working?

EDIT:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public update() {
 if (hasStartDateChanges || hasEndDateChanges) {
        taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
            setNotifications(changedTaskDto, NotificationType.TASK_UPDATE_TIME, true, taskEntity.getProject().getCompany().getId(), currentUser);
        });
    }
}

public void setNotifications(TaskDto task, NotificationType type, boolean visibleForClient, Long companyId, UserDto currentUser) {
    ProjectEntity projectEntity = repository.findBy(task.getProjectId());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply inject the TaskExecutor or TaskScheduler and use it:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public static class DemoRestController {

    private final TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public DemoRestController(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
            System.out.println("Hello from Task");
        });
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

From the docs:

> 42. Task Execution and Scheduling In the absence of an Executor bean in the context, Spring Boot auto-configures a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor
>       with sensible defaults that can be automatically associated to
>       asynchronous task execution (@EnableAsync) and Spring MVC asynchronous
>       request processing.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-task-execution-scheduling

Comment: Can I also do this in my Service annotated class because all my logic is there? Or does this only work in the RestController annotated class?

Comment: You can use in any spring component. This is just and example

Comment: @user1007522 `@RestController`, `@Service`, `@Repository` and a few others are basically `@Component`s as far as the application container is concerned. Some do a bit more than others, but you can use any of basic functions like dependency injection in any of them.

Comment: I just tried it. The function returns immediate but the other function is not executed. Do I need to annotate something with @EnableAsync? Because now the function is called breakpoint triggers but when the return is called the function stops.

Comment: What type of application do you have?

Comment: Spring boot for rest services. Is it because the function I execute in the execute() block is saving things and it's a @transactional function from where it's called?

Comment: The code I posted in the answer is working. Have you tried to set a breakpointt in the execute?

Comment: I get could not initialize proxy - no session. Because that method is saving something to the db.

Comment: can you please add the code of the whole method to the question that I can see what you are doing?

Comment: I have updated my post. I think because I'm on a new thread the repository can't fetch anything anymore.

Comment: The transactional is only for the method not for the code that runs in the executor. If you want to have this code transactional I suggest to put it in it's own bean then inject this bean and call it from the executor